# What is the best option for sending multiple events in a single action to google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been doing a ton of research on here and various forums/blogs but I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer.

I've got an option for users to download multiple files at once from my website.  Due to this, we cant use a single event to send the labels of all of the file names, and we don't generate virtual page views for each of the downloaded files to track either.  I can send the filenames in one label while separated by a comma, but they just show up in the same label entry instead of broken up.

We don't load a new page when the download happens as a file is just downloaded directly through the browser.  Is there a downside to sending multiple event calls (one for each file) on the single button action? The traffic is relatively low so hitting the call cap isn't a concern.

I also looked at custom dimensions but you can only send one value for a custom dimension at a time.

Any insight/advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there are no problems in Analytics if you send more than one event in a single interaction.

Comment: Thanks Michele.  I went the route of sending multiple events in one action and its working solidly as of now.

Comment: You are welcome :) Mark answer as useful, pls